# Variable in Ruby Regex

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have an variable "titel" which contains the title name some articles. Inside a given *.ent-File (XML Entities) i have a string "| You need to change the HOLDER entity in the de-DE/TITEL.ent file |" which i want to replace with "MyCompany".

So I tried:

```
text = File.read("#{$titel}/de-DE/#{$titel.ent}")
new_contents = text.gsub(/"| You need to change the HOLDER entity in the de-DE/#{$titel}.ent file |"/, "XCOM AG")
puts new_contents
File.open("#{$titel}/de-DE/#{$titel.ent}", "w") { |file| file.puts new_contents}
```

Now it says it isn't valid code.
Maybe I must change anything inside the regex?

Comment: Why do you want to use a regular expression? `new_contents = text.gsub("| You need to change the HOLDER entity in the de-DE/#{$titel}.ent file |", "XCOM AG")` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expression literals use `/` as a delimiter:

```
text.gsub(/"| You need to change the HOLDER entity in the de-DE/#{$titel}.ent file |"/, "XCOM AG")
#         ^                                                    ^
#       start                                                 end
```

To use the delimiter or a metacharacter within the regular expression, you have to backslash-escape them, i.e. `/` becomes `\/`, `|` ([alternation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Alternation)) becomes `\|` and so on:

```
text.gsub(/\| You need to change the HOLDER entity in the de-DE\/#{$titel}\.ent file \|/, "XCOM AG")
```

(I've also removed the quotes from the regexp)

But as already [noted by cremno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29675442/variable-in-ruby-regex#comment47489199_29675442), you can use a string instead:

```
text.gsub("| You need to change the HOLDER entity in the de-DE/#{$titel}.ent file |", "XCOM AG")
```